# Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/data'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have copied the database backup files from my local drive to the docker container using the following commands.

```
docker cp "E:\Book Store\BookStoreDb.bak" a4601f635101:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

[image]

And when I tried to restore the database from the sql server, using the following command.

```
RESTORE DATABASE BookStoreDb
FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data'
WITH MOVE 'BookStoreDb' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/BookStoreDb.mdf',
MOVE 'BookStoreDb_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/BookStoreDb_log.ldf';
```

I got an error as

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/data'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

What could be wrong here on the command? What is causing this problem to occurs?